# Windows 10 run an interactive scheduled task to run for any interactive user

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I want to setup a windows 10 task scheduler to run a GUI based tasked interactively for any logged on user. Right now we have to explicitly specify the user name, so the task can only be run for this specific user.  This scheduled task will be deployed on 1000s of computers for 100s of companies - all Windows 10, but of many, many difference configurations (pro, enterprise, OEM, site modified).

Looking at other scheduled tasks I see two possibilities:

"nt authority\interactive" - this is used by adobe acrobat update task

"Builtin\users" - this is used by some office tasks

Will either of these work for my purpose?  Are they the "right" group to use that can be deployed on many disparate Win10 installations?

thanks!

Comment: I assume these computers are part of an AD domain, and that you are planning to deploy this via GPO. Is the software already in place on all of the systems? Does the solution have to be through task scheduler or are other solutions acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Some of our customers are domain, lots are small and just use workgroup.  The deploy of the scheduler task will be through an MSI installer for our product.  The solution has to be through task scheduler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want the application to start when any user logs on, I'd suggest the `builtin\users` security context.  If the application needs admin rights, you would need to do a few things differently. Here's an example of the syntax you would use to have notepad run whenever a user logs on:

`schtasks /create /ru builtin\users /sc onlogon /tn "Notepad On Logon" /tr C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe`

Keep in mind, your installer will need admin rights to add the scheduled task.

Another thing to keep in mind: if the path to your executable has spaces, you'll need to use both double and single quotes around the path. So you'd use something like this:

`/tr "'C:\path with spaces\myApplication.exe'"`

Comment: Perfect - thanks!  Works like a charm.

Comment: For me it worked when I replaced `C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe` with `notepad.exe`.